# (.NET) MVC and WCF (REST vs. SOAP) and using them together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest, soap

I'm looking to build two WCF Services that can be consumed by an ASP.NET MVC Controller or by each other.

Essentially the service will generate an (XML) DataContract which can be consumed by another service.

> A. The OutputService1 would output an object, InputService2 would take it as input and save it. In this case the user would e.g. Click a link in
>   the MVC app to force the message transfer.

Or

> B. OutputService1 would give the output to an ASP.NET MVC controller which would then put it in a file and give it to the user to save. The user could then upload it via the MVC app to InputService2 in the near future.

So far I have the two services and the .NET MVC app. I've tested several scenarios and I am not quite satisfied with the results.

Here is how I was able to send an object via. an input form in a View then passed via the controller to the WCF supporting REST. The output of the OutputService1 includes `<?xml version="1.0"?>` when using REST. The InputService2 will only accept the rest of the XML without that first line.

The REST WCF services are similar to this example: http://forums.asp.net/t/1830710.aspx/1

IInputOutputService.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "Input")]
ServiceRequestStatus Input(MyDataContract mdc);
```

Web.Config

```
  <service name="myns.InputOutputService">
    <endpoint address="/" binding="webHttpBinding" name="InputOutputEndPoint"
      contract="myns.IInputOutputService" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MetaDataExchangeEndpoint"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
...
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="restBehavior">
    <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

The .NET MVC portion is similar to this example: [Passing object with WCF RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552971/passing-object-with-wcf-restful)

MVC MyView.cshtml

```
<form method="post" action='@Url.Action("TestWCFRest")'>
    <textarea name="xml" id="WCFTestData" rows="10" cols="50">        
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <MyDataContract xmlns="myns" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <item1>100</item1><item2>0.5</item2>
        </MyDataContract>
    </textarea>
    <br />        
    <input id="Url" name="Url" type="text" value="http://localhost/ProjectName/WCFTestService.svc/Input" size="80" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test WCF input"/>
</form>
```

.NET MVC MyController.cs

```
    // Added to avoid validating the XML 
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult TestWCFRest(string xml, string url)
    {

        byte[] reqData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = " application/xml";
        req.ContentLength = xml.Length;
        req.Proxy = null;
        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);

        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        string code = resp.StatusCode.ToString();
        return Content(code);
    }
```

If I try to add a ServiceReference to the WCF Service(s), and convert the XML to the datacontract inside MVC is this possible or a bad idea?

```
    public ActionResult TestWCFRest(string xml, string url)
    {
        InputOutputServiceClient iosc = new InputOutputServiceClient();
        // Need to convert the XML to MyDataContract
        ...?
        iosc.Input(myDataContractObj);
    }
```

Should I be using REST instead of SOAP? I tried outputting via SOAP the DataContract class from OutputService1 and then manually sending it to InputService2 using `HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse` but didn't get it working (yet). The file that the user gets doesn't necessarily need to be human readable, but the services may be open to external clients at some point if that matters.

Is there a better approach to using .NET MVC and WCF Services? The main theme is that the two services InputService and OutputService need to communicate directly with each other when commanded via the User in MVC, as well as being able to output the output directly to the user (XML file) and take the same file as an input.

Basically, this approach works other then the extra line in the XML outputted. However, is there a better way, and should the XML be converted to a DataContract object and passed to the user? Should the OutputService preferably output SOAP or REST XML? It seems a little akward to be using `HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse` to send the data to the service.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Edited. Just used to talking about MVC, WCF, Webforms etc. :)